# something wrong when i append src to images every iterate for every N seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

Something goes wrong while i do this with my javascript code

```
 function sleep(delay) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
    }
    //submit data with jQuery AJAX
    function onSuccess(data) {
        var millisecondsToWait = $("#range").val() * 1000;

        obj= JSON.parse(data)
        for (var x of obj.Images_Url)
        {
            $("#left_image").attr('src', x.Item1);
            $("#right_image").attr('src', x.Item2);
            sleep(millisecondsToWait);
        }
```

so what executed is only the last item in `obj.Images_Url` and the others are not

**for example let say we have json string as this**

```
"Images_Url":[{"Item1":"url1","Item2":"url2"},{"Item1":"url3","Item2":"url4"},{"Item1":"url5","Item2":"url6"}]
```

what only appear is images with `url5` and `url6`
i don't know why is that happening 
but i assume that the browser or the render hangup since i'm not using any threads or Tasks ,So Please any one got any idea how to fix this

Comment: Are you sure the code/json string is correct? `item1` != `Item1`

Comment: Omg... don't do things like `sleep`. You only have a single thread, you certainly do not want to block it. Use asynchronous timers such as `setInterval` or `setTimeout`.

Comment: when i'm BackEnd coding i simply using Task.Delay and async and await to do such a thing but i'm not really good with javascript sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendering occurs when the execution queue has been emptied and that is when your code runs to completion. Therefore, you will only see the last 2 images.

You could do something like this:

```js
let numbersToShow = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    left = document.getElementById('left'),
    right = document.getElementById('right');

showNumbersByPairAtInterval(numbersToShow, 2000);

function showNumbersByPairAtInterval(numbersToShow, interval, index) {
  index = index || 0;
  
  let slice = numbersToShow.slice(index, index + 2),
      nextIndex = index + 2;
  
  left.textContent = slice[0];
  right.textContent = slice[1];
  
  if (nextIndex <= numbersToShow.length - 1) {
      setTimeout(showNumbersByPairAtInterval.bind(
          null, 
          numbersToShow, 
          interval, 
          nextIndex
      ), 2000);
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="left"></span>
<span id="right"></span>
```

Comment: with a little modification it works like a charm Thx

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to iterate through the array of image url's at a timed pace you could do something like this, which would be at 1 second intervals:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
var k = 0;
var total = obj.Images_Url.length;
setInterval(function () {
    if (k < total) {
        $("#left_image").attr('src', obj.Images_Url[k].Item1);
        $("#right_image").attr('src', obj.Images_Url[k].Item2);
        k++;
    }
}, 1000);
```